# Boolean vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation

In the following, why is $\top$ used as a superscript?

> We first must consider the vector space used to model the boolean truth values of $\mathbb{B}$. Coecke et al. (2010) suggest, as boolean vector space, the space $B$ with the basis $\\{\top, \bot \\}$, where $\top = [1 \quad 0]^{\top}$ is interpreted as `true’, and $\bot = [0 \quad 1]^{\top}$ as ‘false’.

Neither the paper from which this is from (http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/edward.grefenstette/GrefenstetteTFDS.pdf) nor the cited paper, clarify this.

In addition, what do  $[1 \quad 0]^{\top}$ and $[0 \quad 1]^{\top}$ refer to?

Comment: Column vectors, I'm guessing.

Comment: Ah, so the notation $\top$ is used to denote the transposition of a row, in addition to denoting the logical constant true?

Comment: Yes... very bad choice of symbols, to use $\top$ for TRUE and also for [Transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose).

Comment: Yeah, unfortunate choices there.  Easily avoidable.

Comment: As you can see from the examples in the page, an element of the domain $D$ (e.g. $\text {john}$) is mapped to a vector $[1,0,0]^{\text T}$ and a predicate $P$ to a matrix $\text {M}_{\text P}$ that has a column "TRUE" if the corresponding element of the domain $D$ belongs to predicate $P$. Thus, multiplying (matrix and vector) $\text {M}_{\text P} \times \text {john}$ produces $\top$ because $P(john)$ holds.

Comment: Ok, but I also fail to see how $\textbf[M}^P$ relates to the formula defined in sum notation in the article.